# How do we check if the user is logging in or registering?

Tags: filters, login

I am changing the text on the login page using this filter:

```
function filter_register_text() {
    return "<p class='message register'>Registering for this site will give you access to the admin panel to add new products with images and useful files for others to download and choose open product licenses.</p>";
}

add_filter('login_message', 'filter_register_text');
```

I just want to show the text if the user **signs up** on the website, not for users who just want to **log in**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to check if the `action` parameter is set & equal to `register`:

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'register' )
    add_filter( 'login_message', 'filter_register_text' );
```